# (need help) score not showing in text view , (need help) score is not showing in text view, here is my java code

Tags: image, textview

```
private void checkForMatchingImages() {
    int currentImage = images.get(0);
    int sameImageCount = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < imageViews.size(); i++) {
        if (images.get(i) == currentImage) {
            sameImageCount++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    int calculatedScore = calculateScore(sameImageCount);
    score = score + calculatedScore;

    scoreTextView.setText("Score : " + score);

    if (sameImageCount > 1) {
        playDifferentImageSound();
    } else {
        playSameImageSound();
    }
}
```

i made an android application , using 6 pictures and calculating the score , but the score does not appear in the text view in the layout , is there something wrong with my code ?